# How do I get my JScrollpane to expand in Height instead of width?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel, imageicon

I have a small question for you, I have this JScrollPane I am working on, and it only expands in width. But instead, I would like it to expand in height.

```
private void setImageLibPanel() {
ExtraScrollPanel = new JPanel();
MidLeftPanel.removeAll();
if (project.getImgCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < project.getImgCount(); i++) {
        JLabel temp = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon tempIcon = project.getNextImage();
        temp.setIcon(tempIcon);
        ExtraScrollPanel.add(temp);
    }
}
JScrollPane imageLibScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
imageLibScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
imageLibScrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
imageLibScrollPane.setViewportView(ExtraScrollPanel);
MidLeftPanel.add(imageLibScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

How can I do this?

With regards,
Black Magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard Java naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper case character.

You are adding JLabels to a JPanel. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default.

Instead I would use a JList. Add the icons the list. See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

In the future post a proper `SSCCE` when you ask a question. You have been given this advice before. Next time I will not read your question unless a `SSCCE` is posted.